# Designing OpenCV GUI with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, opencv

I want to customize Qt's GUI

Here is the Default Qt OpenCV GUI

[image: When You Click on Display Properties Button]

I want to place createButton on Menu.

[image]

How can I do that?

Below is my code

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

void callbackButton2(int state, void* userData){

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//QApplication a(argc, argv);
//MainWindow w;
//w.show();
cv::VideoCapture vc(0);
if(!vc.isOpened()) perror("Can't Open WebCam");

const char* winname = "WebCam";
cv::namedWindow(winname,CV_GUI_EXPANDED);

cv::createButton("button6",callbackButton2,NULL,CV_PUSH_BUTTON,1);
for(;;){
    cv::Mat frm;
    vc>>frm;
    if(!frm.empty()) imshow(winname,frm);
    if(cv::waitKey(20)==27) break;
}
vc.release();
cv::destroyWindow(winname);

return 0;
// return a.exec();
}
```

The code above simply opens webcam and display it on the screen. But for my next application, I need to customize gui and place it on to the menu.

BTW I searched through the fllowing link, and I couldn't find how can I customize the GUI. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about if you can customize the OpenCv Qt windows but you can code your own window and then show the openCv image, using something similiar to [this](https://github.com/javiertoja/KGuardiant/blob/master/KGuardiantClient/customtab.cpp), you can retrive the cv:Mat immage and convert it to a Qimage object then show the object in a Qt graphicsview using a QPixmap.